# Hyperboloid with POV-Ray

Tags: povray

I want to draw exactly the same hyperboloids like on the German wikipedia page (just without the axis):

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid

For example, I know how to draw a hyperboloid of two sheets:

```
#include "colors.inc"           

background {White}
camera { orthographic
  location <0, 35, -200>
  up  <0.0, 25.0, 0.0>
  right <33, 0.0, 0.0>
  look_at <0, 0, 0>
}

light_source { <-10, 20, -25> color White }       

light_source { <100, 50, -200> color White}


intersection {
  quadric {
    <1, -1, 1> <0, 0, 0><0, 0, 0>(1)    

    texture {  

      pigment { color rgb<0,0,1>}
    } 

  }      

  object { box {<-15, -5, -5>, <15, 5, 5> texture{ pigment { Clear } }  } }
  bounded_by { box {<-15, -15, -5>, <15, 15, 5> } }


  no_shadow
}
```

But I want it to look like on the wiki page. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you meaning something like this?

```
// render with +UA
#include "colors.inc"           

//background {White}
camera { orthographic
  location <0, 10, -30>
  look_at <0, 0, 0>
}

light_source { <-10, 20, -25> color White }       

//light_source { <100, 50, -200> color White}


#declare my_hyperboloid=intersection {
  quadric {
    <1, -1, 1> <0, 0, 0><0, 0, 0>(12)    
  }      
  object { box {<-20, -10, -10>, <20, 10, 10> texture{ pigment { Clear } }  } }
  bounded_by { box {<-20, -20, -10>, <20, 20, 10> } }
  no_shadow
}

object{my_hyperboloid scale <1,0.8,1> texture{pigment{color rgbt<0.44, 0.87, 0.87,0.1>}}}
```

[image: Render of above code]

I suggest you to ask to the POV-Ray newsgroup (http://news.povray.org/) for a more detailed answer.